# Adding attribute table to raster in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, attribute-table

I would like to add attributes to a raster stored in a postgis database. I use the following command to insert the raster in the database:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4236 -I -C -M /home/user/mysrc/outlabeled.tif public.test | psql -d template_postgis
```

The raster `outlabeled.tif` is in fact a one-band raster with a label per group of pixels (object). Then I have computed .txt files with attributes that I'd like to add to the raster (like an attribute table in a shapefile). Is it possible to do it (and how)? So far I've the impression that the only way to do it is actually to add a raster band (and not text files). If it's not possible, would an attribute table added with gdal before the importation do the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding your raster file to the *template_postgis* database as the *public.test* table you can use ALTER TABLE for creating new columns in *public.test* and then UPDATE statement to populate them with corresponding attributes. But this will be only one row per raster.

If you have multiple rasters in *template_postgis* table and you want to join them with a separate table of attributes, you need to use some key to bind them by a JOIN statement. For example you can import raster with a **flag -F** (which adds a column with the name of the file).